# Issue in executing a batch file using PeopleCode in Application engine program

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I want to execute a batch file using People code in Application Engine Program. But The program have an issue returning Exec code as a non zero value **(Value - 1)**.

**Below is people code snippet below.**

```
Global File &FileLog; 

Global string &LogFileName, &Servername, &commandline; 
Local string &Footer; 

If &Servername = "PSNT" Then 

    &ScriptName = "D: && D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat"; 

End-If; 

&commandline = &ScriptName; 

/* Need to commit work or Exec will fail */ 
CommitWork(); 

&ExitCode = Exec("cmd.exe /c " | &commandline, %Exec_Synchronous + %FilePath_Absolute); 

If &ExitCode <> 0 Then 
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, ("Batch File Call Failed! Exit code returned by script was " | &ExitCode)); 
End-If;
```

Any help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you doing `&ScriptName = "D: && D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat";` instead of `&ScriptName = "D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat";`

Comment: I want to change the directory to D drive and execute the script.

Comment: You should be able to do `&exitCode = Exec("D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat", %Exec_Synchronous + %FilePath_Absolute);`  I think the `"D: && D:\psoft.."` is syntactically invalid, which is causing your error.

Comment: So, no need to provide cmd.exe /c?

Comment: I tried using the following:  &exitCode = Exec("D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat", %Exec_Synchronous + %FilePath_Absolute); But it didnt work. I saw the message - Batch File Call Failed! Exit code returned by script was 2

Comment: Not that I know of.  I didn't have to when I used `Exec`.  You can, but it's not necessary.  The `cmd.exe` isn't the problem.  It's the `D && D...` that's the problem.  Try running that from the command line and you'll see that it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you successfully run `D:\psoft\PT854\appserv\prcs\RNBatchFile.bat` from a command prompt on the same server where you're running your App Engine?

Comment: Can you provide the trace file?

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to do a trace of the execution.

Thoughts:

- Can you log on the the process scheduler you are running this on and execute the script OK?
- Is the AE being scheduled or called at run-time?
- You should not need to change directory as you are using a fully qualified path to the script.
- you should not need to call "cmd /c" as this will create an additional shell for you application to run within, making debuging harder, etc.

Run a trace, and drop us the output. :) HTH

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the working directory to D: inside of the script instead? You are invoking two commands and I'm wondering what the shell is returning to exec. I'm assuming you wrote your script to give the appropriate return code and that isn't the problem.

I couldn't tell from the question text, but are you looking for a negative result, such as -1? I think return codes are usually positive. 0 for success, some other positive number for failure. Negative numbers may be acceptable, but am wondering if Exec doesn't like negative numbers?

Perhaps the PeopleCode ChDir function still works as an alternative to two commands in one line? I haven't tried it for a LONG time.

Another alternative that gives you significant control over the process is to use java.lang.Runtime.exec from PeopleCode: http://jjmpsj.blogspot.com/2010/02/exec-processes-while-controlling-stdin.html.